# how to count specific words from a pandas Series?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, attributeerror

I am trying to count the number of keywords from a pandas DataFrame as such:

```
df = pd.read_csv('amazon_baby.csv')
selected_words = ['awesome', 'great', 'fantastic', 'amazing', 'love', 'horrible', 'bad', 'terrible', 'awful', 'wow', 'hate']
```

The selected_words have to be counted from the Series:    df['review']

i have tried

```
def word_counter(sent):
a={}
for word in selected_words:
    a[word] = sent.count(word)
return a
```

and then

```
df['totalwords'] = df.review.str.split()
df['word_count'] = df.totalwords.apply(word_counter)

----------------------------------------------------------------------------
----> 1 df['word_count'] = df.totalwords.apply(word_counter)

c:\users\admin\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py in apply(self, func, convert_dtype, args, **kwds)
   3192             else:
   3193                 values = self.astype(object).values
-> 3194                 mapped = lib.map_infer(values, f, convert=convert_dtype)
   3195 
   3196         if len(mapped) and isinstance(mapped[0], Series):

pandas/_libs/src\inference.pyx in pandas._libs.lib.map_infer()

<ipython-input-51-cd11c5eb1f40> in word_counter(sent)
  2     a={}
  3     for word in selected_words:
----> 4         a[word] = sent.count(word)
  5     return a

AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'count'
```

can someone help..?
i am guessing it is because of some fault value in the series that is not a string.
.
.

some people have tried helping but the issue is that the individual **cells** in the DataFrame have sentences in them.

I need to extract a count of selected words, preferably in dictionary form and store them in a new column in the same dataFrame with the corresponding rows.

[image: image of first few lines csv]
[Data in csv format](https://d396qusza40orc.cloudfront.net/phoenixassets/amazon_baby.csv)

Comment: Welcome to SO. Could you provide an example code?

Comment: post your dataframe

Comment: added the csv file link.

Comment: selected_words have to be extracted  from a sentence..                                           
i added the csv file though it is a bit large..                                                       
format is as df = DataFrame(columns = ['name','review','rating']).         &  df['review'] has reviews i.e sentences from which to extract count  ,                         df['word_count'][i] = count of every selected_word from df["review"][i]

Comment: added a snapshot of the csv file in excel

Answer (score 5):

Suppose your dataframe looks like this,

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'A': ['awesome', 'great', 'fantastic', 'amazing', 'love', 'horrible', 'bad', 'terrible', 'awful', 'wow', 'hate','great', 'fantastic', 'amazing', 'love', 'horrible']})
print(df)
    A
0   awesome
1   great
2   fantastic
3   amazing
4   love
5   horrible
6   bad
7   terrible
8   awful
9   wow
10  hate
11  great
12  fantastic
13  amazing
14  love
15  horrible

selected_words=['awesome','great','fantastic']

df.loc[df['A'].isin(selected_words),'A'].value_counts()
[out]
great        2
fantastic    2
awesome      1
Name: A, dtype: int64
```

Comment: selected_words have to be extracted  from a sentence..                                           
i added the csv file though it is a bit large..                                                       
format is as df = DataFrame(columns = ['name','review','rating']).         &  df['review'] has reviews i.e sentences from which to extract count  ,                         df['word_count'][i] = count of every selected_word from df["review"][i]

Comment: use `df.loc[df['A'].str.contains('|'.join(selected_words)),'A'].value_counts()` and tell  me or post a simple dataframe with 5 rows and post its expected output df

Answer (score 0):

Repeated `list.count` in a loop would work, albeit inefficiently, with a `list` of values. Complexity would be O(*m* x *n*), where *m* is the number of selected values and *n* is the total number of values.

With Pandas you can use optimized methods which ensure O(*n*) complexity. In this case, you can use [`value_counts`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) followed by [`reindex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.reindex.html):

```
res = df['A'].value_counts().reindex(selected_words)

print(res)

awesome      1
great        2
fantastic    2
Name: A, dtype: int64
```

Or, as per [@pyd's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52222123/9209546), filter first and then use `value_counts`. Both solutions will have O(*n*) complexity.

Answer (score 0):

In your question you seems to be implementing a dict for the count. @pyd have posted a good solution for the counting. The result produced is not a dict. If you are looking for a dictionary as output take a look at this code posted below, which is basically an extension of the solution provided by pyd.

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'A': ['awesome', 'great', 'fantastic', 'amazing', 'love', 'horrible', 'bad', 'terrible', 'awful', 'wow', 'hate','great', 'fantastic', 'amazing', 'love', 'horrible']})

def get_count_dict(data, selected_words):

    count_dict = {}

    counts = data.loc[data['A'].isin(selected_words), 'A'].value_counts()

    for i in range(len(counts.index.tolist())):
        count_dict[counts.index.tolist()[i]] = counts[i]

    return count_dict

selected_words=['awesome','great','fantastic']

get_count_dict(df, selected_words)

Output : {'fantastic': 2, 'great': 2, 'awesome': 1}
```