# count specific word in each series of Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I've been looking for the way to count the occurrence of specific words(dates) in DataFrame. In detail, I'd like to know how many each element in dates_list exists in each columns. Could anyone give me advices ?? Thank you so much.
I found out the link below but my skill is lack of making use of this.

[reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59475298/counting-specific-keywords-in-a-dataframe)

```
dates_list(No duplicates)

['2021-06-22', '2021-06-23', '2021-06-24', '2021-06-25', '2021-06-30', '2021-07-01', '2021-07-02', '2021-07-03', '2021-07-04', '2021-07-05', '2021-07-06', '2021-07-07', '2021-07-08', '2021-07-09', '2021-07-10', '2021-07-11', '2021-07-12', '2021-07-13', '2021-07-14', '2021-07-15', '2021-07-16', '2021-07-17', '2021-07-18', '2021-07-19',・・・・・]
```

```
push_df

push_a_date,push_b_date,push_c_date,push_d_date
2021-07-09,2021-07-10,2021-07-14,2021-07-18,
2021-07-09,2021-07-26,2021-07-30,2021-07-18
2021-07-22,2021-07-23,2021-07-27,2021-07-31,
2021-07-23,2021-07-26,2021-07-29,2021-08-02,
2021-07-24,2021-07-18,2021-07-30,2021-08-03,
,,,,,,,,
```

```
my ideal output
           push_a_date,push_b_date,push_c_date,push_d_date          
2021-07-09.   2.            0.         0.         0
2021-07-18.   0.            1          0.         2
2021-07-30.   0.            0.         2.         0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.melt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html) with [`crosstab`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html):

```
df1 = df.melt()
df = pd.crosstab(df1['value'], df1['variable'])
print (df)
variable    push_a_date  push_b_date  push_c_date  push_d_date
value                                                         
2021-07-09            2            0            0            0
2021-07-10            0            1            0            0
2021-07-14            0            0            1            0
2021-07-18            0            1            0            2
2021-07-22            1            0            0            0
2021-07-23            1            1            0            0
2021-07-24            1            0            0            0
2021-07-26            0            2            0            0
2021-07-27            0            0            1            0
2021-07-29            0            0            1            0
2021-07-30            0            0            2            0
2021-07-31            0            0            0            1
2021-08-02            0            0            0            1
2021-08-03            0            0            0            1
```

If need also change/add datetimes by your list:

```
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)
df = df.reindex(pd.to_datetime(dates_list), fill_value=0)
```

Comment: wow,I didn't know this method(.crosstab).  I could get ideal output by your code .Thank you so much !